# Django Rest Framework + React rest hooks CORS error

Tags: reactjs, django, typescript, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to integrate both React frontend and Django & [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) backend.

I am using [rest-hooks](https://resthooks.io/) to fetch the data. I get CORS errors **only when defining `urlRoot = 'api/somemodel'` in the resource**.
But I get the data from the API whenever I define  `urlRoot = 'api/somemodel.json'` (adding `.json` to the resource `urlRoot`).

#### CategoryResource.ts

```js
import { Resource } from '@rest-hooks/rest';
import { API_URL } from '../utils/server';

export default class CategoryResource extends Resource {
    readonly id: number | undefined = undefined;
    readonly name: string = '';
    readonly description: string = '';

    pk() {
        return this.id?.toString();
    }

    static urlRoot = API_URL + 'categories.json';
}
```

The above code works only for `useResource(CategoryResource.list(), {})`, but, whenever I fetch one category with `useResource(CategoryResource.detail(), { id })` it returns some network error due to the URL format: `http://localhost:8000/api/categories.json/1`. But it should be `categories/1.json`.

So, I thought, if I am able to use Postman to fetch all the categories in JSON format when sending request to `http://localhost:8000/api/categories` I should use that, but then I get CORS error.

#### CORS Configuration

My Django configuration is allowing all origins from `settings.py`: `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True`. And again, it does work with the first approach. But anyway, this is my configuration file in Python:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    ...
    'django_filters',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

# CORS // I have tried switching all of these
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

# CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
#     'http://localhost:3000',
# ]
```

Comment: First of all you shouldn't use `.json` in your request url. Can you please also explain the last part of your question? When you do CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS which you should on your local machine only it works, without the `.json` in url?

Comment: Do you have the cors properly configured? Like cors middleware etc. Can you please update your question with CORS related settings from your django application?

Comment: I thought it wouldn't be necessary since I can already fetch data.

Comment: @SadanA. but anyway, I added it to the question.

Comment: have you added this in your settings.py
```ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']```

Comment: @Keval, yes it was autogenerated by Django-admin

Answer (score 0):

I just appended a slash to the `urlRoot` and all other URLs in the frontend and it worked. No longer CORS error.

#### CategoryResource.ts

```js
import { Resource } from '@rest-hooks/rest';
import { API_URL } from '../utils/server';

export default class CategoryResource extends Resource {
    readonly id: number | undefined = undefined;
    readonly name: string = '';
    readonly description: string = '';

    pk() {
        return this.id?.toString();
    }

    static urlRoot = API_URL + 'categories/';
}
```

#### Other URLs

```js
const category = useResource(CategoryResource.detail(), { id: query.get('category') + '/' });
```

I guess it would work fine for now, but is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should Try `corsheaders`  Like below ... just another approach ..

You should setup you config like this

First Install corsheaders

```
$ pip install corsheaders
```

then modify settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
..
'corsheaders', # To Connect API with React App. 
]
```

Add this line in middle right above CommonMiddleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', #this one
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

and also these lines

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://example.com",
    "https://sub.example.com",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000"
]
```

And to connect in React app .Use `"axios": "^0.21.1",` to full fill the requests .
Code would be like that ....

Create a Dir with name you like , In this case I would like to name services
then I wil add two files named Services.js and RestDataSource.js

```
//services.js
export const baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/";
export const headers = {
  "Content-type": "application/json",
};
```

and

```
//RestDataSource.js
import Axios from "axios";

export class RestDataSource {
  constructor(base_url) {
    this.BASE_URL = base_url;
  }
  GetData(callback) {
    this.SendRequest("get", this.BASE_URL, callback);
  }
  async SendRequest(method, url, callback) {
    callback(
      (
        await Axios.request({
          method: method,
          url: url,
        })
      ).data
    );
  }
```

}

To merge you data in Component ...

```
//fileName.js 
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { RestDataSource } from "./services/RestDataSource";

export class IsolatedTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [],
    };
    this.dataSource = new RestDataSource(
      "http://localhost:8000/api/somemodel"
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colSpan="5" className="bg-info text-white text-center h4 p-2">
              (Isolated) Category
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>model name</th>

            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.products.map((p) => (
            <tr key={p.id}>
              {/* <td>{p.id}</td> */}
              <td>{p.title}</td>

              <td />
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.dataSource.GetData((data) => this.setState({ products: data }));
  }
}
```

In the last Import the component where you want ... that would definitely work ..I am also using that approach you can check on this git repo https://github.com/faisalnazik/Django-REST-framework-React.JS-Typescript.git